# Assignment of list over tuple unpacking returns tuple, not list [Python]

Tags: python, list, tuples, unpack

In Python, when executing the following code:

```py
a = [b,c,d] = 0,1,2
print(type(a),a)
```

It yields a **tuple** object:

```py
<class 'tuple'> (0, 1, 2)
```

Why not a **list** object:

```py
<class 'list'> [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: The line is shorthand for 2 lines. The assignment to `a` is effectively `a = 0,1,2` which makes `a` a tuple. The `b,c,d` doesn't matter  when assigning to `a`